# Add a line in a txt file

Tags: c#

I have a txt file with data such as the following:

```
:10FF800000040B4E00040B4E00047D1400047D148D
:10FF900000040B4E0004CF6200040B4E00040B4E15
:10FFA00000040B4E00040B4E00040B4E00040B4EDD
:10FFB00000047D1400047D1400047D1400047D14ED
:10FFC00000040B4E000000000000000000000000D4
:10FFD0000000000000040B4E0000000000000000C4
:10FFE0000000000000000000000000000000000011
:10FFF0000000000000000000060000000000BFF844
:020000020000FC
:020000040014E6
:043FF0005AC8A58C7A
:00000001FF
```

what I want to do with my C# program is to add a line after or before a specific line, lets say add the line:

```
:020000098723060
```

before this line:

```
:020000020000FC
```

I have tried using the File.ReadLines("file.txt").Last(); but that just gives me the last one, what if i want the third or fourth? also, is there any way to identify the ":" in the file?

Comment: @Brian "I have tried using the..."

Comment: @MStodd - I should have been more specific.  I meant what he had tried _code-wise_, as in post your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *simplest* way - if you're happy to read the whole file into memory - would be just:

```
public void InsertLineBefore(string file, string lineToFind, string lineToInsert)
{
    List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
    int index = lines.IndexOf(lineToFind);
    // TODO: Validation (if index is -1, we couldn't find it)
    lines.Insert(index, lineToInsert);
    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}

public void InsertLineAfter(string file, string lineToFind, string lineToInsert)
{
    List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(file).ToList();
    int index = lines.IndexOf(lineToFind);
    // TODO: Validation (if index is -1, we couldn't find it)
    lines.Insert(index + 1, lineToInsert);
    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}
```

There are significantly more *efficient* ways of doing this, but this approach is really *simple*.

Comment: Of course, looking at your code, I feel a little hurt in my self-esteem, but, as usual, it is always a pleasure to watch and learn from it

Comment: I'm curious, what more efficient ways of doing it are there? Apart from using an iterator to find the line and only reading lines until the desired one is found (as opposed to loading the whole file), I can't think of any.

Comment: @G.Bach: Precisely that - you'd read the file in one sweep, writing out lines as you read them. For the "after" it's reasonably easy, as you just add the extra line when you've read the one you're looking for. For the "before" it's slightly trickier, as you need to keep a buffer of one line in case the *next* line is the one you're looking for.

Comment: What if I wanted to identify a specific part of the string as if it was an array? something like string x = lines.IndexOf(2)[2]; ?

Comment: From my example, lets say i wanted to get the fourth character in the line number 2 has an F .. string F = lines.IndexOf(1)[3];

Answer (score 3):

A brute force approach

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
using(StreamWrite sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
{
   foreach(string line in lines)
   {
       if(line == ":020000020000FC")
          sw.WriteLine(":020000098723060");
       sw.WriteLine(line);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is better to read and write line by line, especially if the target file tend to be of large size:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Test.txt"))
{
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("TestOut.txt"))
    {
        while (!r.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = r.ReadLine();
            w.WriteLine(line);
            if (line == ":020000020000FC")
                w.WriteLine(":020000098723060");
        }
        w.Close();
        r.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're trying to avoid reading the entire file in due to size, etc...but can't you just read the file and then replace...e.g.

```
var text = readFile(somePath);
writeFile( text.replace(":020000020000FC\n",":020000098723060\n:020000020000FC\n") , somePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, though it may not be the best, it does work:

```
public void AddTextToFile(string filePath, int lineNumber, string txt) //zero based lineNumber
{
        Collection<string> newLines = new Collection<string>(File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList());


        if (lineNumber < newLines.Count)
            newLines.Insert(lineNumber, txt);
        else 
            newLines.Add(txt);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
        {
            foreach (string s in newLines)
                writer.WriteLine(s);
        }
}
```

And to answer your question about determining if ":" exists in a string, the answer is yes,  in the example above, you could check if the line contains it by...

```
if(newLines[idx].Contains(':'))
//do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The ":" character doesn't really help the implementation, the lines are all *newline*-delimited already.

Here's an attempt at a method that doesn't load it all to memory or output to a different file.

**Never cross the streams.**

```
static Int32 GetCharPos(StreamReader s)
{
    var ia = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField;
    Int32 charpos = (Int32)s.GetType().InvokeMember("charPos", ia, null, s, null);
    Int32 charlen = (Int32)s.GetType().InvokeMember("charLen", ia, null, s, null);
    return (Int32)s.BaseStream.Position - charlen + charpos;
}

static void Appsert(string data, string precedingEntry = null)
{
    if (precedingEntry == null)
    {
        using (var filestream = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Append))
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(filestream))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(data);
            return;
        }
    }

    int seekPos = -1;
    using (var readstream = new FileStream(dataPath, 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write))
    using (var writestream = new FileStream(dataPath, 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    using (var tr = new StreamReader(readstream))
    {
        while (seekPos == -1)
        {
            var line = tr.ReadLine();
            if (line == precedingEntry)
                seekPos = GetCharPos(tr);
            else if (tr.EndOfStream)
                seekPos = (int)readstream.Length;
        }

        writestream.Seek(seekPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        readstream.Seek(seekPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int readLength = 0;
        var readBuffer = new byte[4096];
        var writeBuffer = new byte[4096];
        var writeData = tr.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(data + Environment.NewLine);
        int writeLength = writeData.Length;
        writeData.CopyTo(writeBuffer, 0);
        while (true & writeLength > 0)
        {
            readLength = readstream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
            writestream.Write(writeBuffer, 0, writeLength);
            var tmp = writeBuffer;
            writeBuffer = readBuffer;
            writeLength = readLength;
            readBuffer = tmp;
        }                
    }
}
```